# Find the derivate of the f(x)= x^a where a is a rational number

Tags: real-analysis

How can i prove this, if  If S = {x: x> 0}, where a is a rational and f: S → R is defined as  f(x) = x^a , Then f is differentiable at each point of S and f ' is given by f '(x) = ax^(a-1)

Comment: It should be fairly straight-forward to prove from the definitions of differentiable at a point, and of the derivative.

Comment: If you have already (1) the formula for integer $a$ and (2) implicit differentiation, you can write $a = \frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p, q$, rearrange $y = x^{p / q}$ as $y^q = x^p$, differentiate, solve for $y'$, and write the resulting expression in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know that for $n$ an integer, $x^n$ has derivative $nx^{n-1}$, you can use this, the inverse function theorem and the chain rule to derive the result: let $a=p/q$ where $p,q$ are integers, $g(x) = x^p$ and $h(x)=x^{q}$. Then $h^{-1}(y) = y^{1/q}$, and so
$$ g'(x) = px^{p-1} $$
and
$$ (h^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{h'(h^{-1}(x))} = \frac{1}{q(x^{1/q})^{q-1}} = \frac{1}{qx^{1-1/q}} = \frac{1}{q}x^{1/q-1}. $$
Finally, since $f(x) = h^{-1}(g(x))$, the chain rule gives
$$ f'(x) = (h^{-1})'(g(x)) g'(x) = \frac{1}{q} (x^p)^{1/q-1} px^{p-1} = \frac{p}{q} x^{p/q-p+p-1} = \frac{p}{q} x^{p/q-1}. $$

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof that holds for real values of $a$ if we use logs.  I'll stay away from that for this proof.

First, binomial expansion is enough to tell you that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[x^a] = ax^{a-1}
$$
holds for $a = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ (noting that $x^0 = 1$ over $S$).  From there, note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[x^{-1}] = \frac{d}{dx} [1/x] = - \frac 1{x^2}
$$
From the chain rule, it follows that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} [x^{-a}] = \frac{d}{dx}[(x^a)^{-1}] = -\frac{ax^{a-1}}{(x^a)^2} = -ax^{-a-1}
$$
So, the desired formula holds for all integers $a$.

Now, with implicit differentiation: for any integer $q > 0$, we have
$$
y = x^{1/q} \implies y^q = x \implies qy^{q-1}\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 \implies\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{qy^{q-1}} = \frac{1}{q(x^{1/q})^{q-1}} = \frac 1q x^{(1/q) - 1}
$$
Finally, the chain rule tells us that for any integer $p$, we have
$$
\frac d{dx}[x^{p/q}] = \frac{d}{dx}[(x^{1/q})^p] = p(x^{1/q})^{p-1} \cdot \frac 1q x^{1/q - 1} = \frac pq x^{\frac{p-1}{q} + \frac 1q - 1} = \\
\frac pq x^{\frac {p - q}q} = \frac pq x^{\frac {p}q - 1}
$$
Thus, we have reached the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Set

$a = \dfrac{p}{q}, \tag{1}$

where $p, q \in \Bbb Z$ with $q \ne 0$.  Let

$y = f(x), \tag{2}$

so that

$y = x^{\frac{p}{q}};  \tag{3}$

then

$y^q = x^p, \tag{4}$

and we can differentiate (4) using the ordinary rule for integer exponents and the chain rule:

$qy^{q -1} y' = px^{p - 1}. \tag{5}$

We re-arrange (5) a little:

$y^{q -1} y' =\dfrac{p}{q}x^{p - 1}; \tag{6}$

from (3) and (4),

$y^{q - 1} = y^q y^{-1} = x^p x^{-\frac{p}{q}} = x^{p - \frac{p}{q}}= x^{\frac{qp - p}{q}}, \tag{7}$

whence

$y^{1 - q} = x^{\frac{p - qp}{q}}, \tag{8}$

so that

$y' = \dfrac{p}{q} x^{p - 1} x^{\frac{p - qp}{q}} = \dfrac{p}{q} x^{p - 1 + \frac{p - qp}{q}}; \tag{9}$

and since

$p - 1 + \dfrac{p - qp}{q} = \dfrac{qp - q + p -qp}{q} = \dfrac{p}{q} - 1, \tag{10}$

we see that (9) becomes

$y' = \dfrac{p}{q}x^{\frac{p}{q} - 1}. \tag{11}$